# C# reading file into grid (like a chessboard)

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a project, where I'm given a lot of files, which contains different game boards. The boards all square (equal height and width) but varies in size. A small example (15 times 15) can be seen here:

```
.-------------.
|xx x  xxxxxx |
| xx    xxx  x|
|   xxx  xxxx |
|  xx    xxx x|
| xxxx  x x x |
|xx  xxx  x xx|
|   xx @ x  xx|
| x  x    xx x|
|    x  x xx  |
| xxx  xx xxx |
|   xx   xx  x|
|  xxxxxx xxx |
|xx     x  x x|
'-------------'
```

I want these files to get into a two-dimensional array, so I can use them as a game-board.

But I need a little help reading and converting the files into two-dimensional arrays. So far I have (with inspiration from Maximilian Gerhardt solution):

```
class Program
{
    enum FieldElement
    {
        Free, Mine, Piece, Boarder
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        public FieldElement[,] Field {get; set;} 
        public static Program ParseBoard(string board)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C...test.txt"))
            {
                // Finds number of lines in the example
                var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@"C...test.txt").Length;
                Console.WriteLine(lineCount);
                string lines = sr.ReadLine();
                var field = new FieldElement[lineCount-1, lineCount-1];
                for (int y = 0; y < lineCount-1; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < lineCount; x++)
                    {
                        switch (lines[y][x])
                        {
                            case 'X':
                                field[x, y] = FieldElement.Mine;
                                break;
                            case '|':
                            case '-':
                            case '\'':
                                field[x, y] = FieldElement.Boarder;
                                break;
                            case ' ':
                                field[x, y] = FieldElement.Free;
                                break;
                            case '@':
                                field[x, y] = FieldElement.Piece;
                                break;
                            default:
                                Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized character {lines[y][x]} in line {y} at position {x}");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return new Board() { Field = field };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

So to sum up: I would like some help getting from a text file, to a two-dimensional array.

Comment: So, the file would contain exactly as you've shown? Seems pretty straightforward. Read how many lines you have, analyze the line length, etc. Then decide what you're actually going to read it into (i.e. What kind of "grid" do you need? A DataTable? 2D array?). Then try that and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: This is way too broad and shows no effort.

Comment: Step through this code in a debugger to see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A basic parser would go like this: Define your field elements (e.g. as a enum or a class), then parse the string line by line, character by character.

```
enum FieldElement
{
   Free, X, At, Boarder
}    

class Board
{
    public FieldElement[,] Field {get; set;}
    public static Board ParseBoard(string board)
    {
        string[] lines = board.Split("\n");
        var field = new FieldElement[lines[0].Length, lines.Length]; 
        for(int y=0; y < lines.Length; y++)
        {
             for(int x=0; x < lines[y].Length; x++)
             {
                 switch(lines[y][x]) //that's a char
                 {
                     case 'X': 
                        field[x,y] = FieldElement.X; break;
                     case '|':
                     case '-':
                     case '.':
                     case '\'':
                        field[x,y] = FieldElememt.Boarder; break;
                     case ' ':
                        field[x,y] = FieldElement.Free; break;
                     case '@': 
                        field[x,y] = FieldElement.At; break;
                     default: 
                        Console.WriteLine($"Unrecognized character {lines[y][x]} in line {y} at position {x}");
                 }
             }
        }
        return new Board() { Field = field; };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is loading to char array is what you are loking for?

```
var data = File.ReadLines("file path")
    .Select(l => l.ToCharArray())
    .ToArray();
```